# Symfony change ChoiceType multiple expanded input name

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Having **Location** as:

```
id    name        title
---   -----       ------
1     usa         United States of America
2     uk          United Kingdom
3     canada      Canada
```

I have an ** EntityType** form field, named **location**:

```
class OrderType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('location', EntityType::class, array(
            'class'        => Location::class,
            'choice_label' => 'title',
            'choice_name'  => 'name',
            'choice_value' => 'id',
            'multiple'     => true,
            'expanded'     => true,
            'data'         => array(
                'usa', 'canada'
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```

and I want to have, for example, some checkboxes (`EntityType`, `multiple=true`, `expanded=true`) checked (using `data` option).

I set `choice_name` option to location's name, but the `name` form field attribute does not change.

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="order_location_usa" name="order[location][]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" id="order_location_uk" name="order[location][]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" id="order_location_canada" name="order[location][]" value="3">
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the question here? set default values or change the input name ?

Comment: setting default values (checking checkboxes), which I think could be done using data option. The data option needs an array of choice names I think, not sure

Comment: To show default data I suggest you to use the binding object to the form instead of `'data'` form option (this could override it). However, this should work with an array of `Location` instances instead of array of string.

Comment: It is intentionaly not bounded to an entity. I should do it manualy

Comment: Then, you need a query to get these (`use`, `canada`) locations as instances and put them to data option. Use `__toString()` magic method to show default label, thus you can remove `choice_label`, `choice_name` and `choice_value` because `EntityType` is able to know that you must use the `id` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you can pass in an entity, you could do this:

```
'choice_name' => function($location){
    return $location->getName();
}
```

Otherwise, 'name' is not defined and that's why it is blank. Documentation is here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-name

So `choice_name` is callable (a function).